# Copying Content from a WSS 3.0 Site to SharePoint 2010 Enterprise

Tags: 2010, wss-3.0, sharepoint-enterprise, content

We are in the process of migrating from one Team Foundation Server instance which was using WSS 3.0 to a new instance running SharePoint 2010 Enterprise. We have quite a bit of content in the various team project portal sites, including calendars, wiki pages and documents.

How can we move the content from the old server to the new server?

Answer (score 2):

DISCLAIMER : Have never tried this so not sure whether this is the best solution.

You should be able to copy the contents by a database backup and restore it into the new SharePoint 2010 farm. Create a new web application with the new attached db. You would also require to upgrade the db using powershell to maintain the same version as that of the existing ones in the server.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to upgrade the DB? Also, can you provide a link with more detail on this process? _I_ get what you mean, but I'd like to provide out Operations people with a page to go look at.

Comment: `Upgrade-SPContentDatabase` is the Powershell way to do that. Check this technet article for detailed usage - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607813.aspx . Also visit this post for upgrading process to SharePoint 2010 - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx . Good Luck.

Comment: So, what will be the result after attaching the second database? Would we have the same structure of sites and subsites, just at a different URL?

Comment: A couple of remarks: Make sure you carefully follow the "Before you begin" part of the Upgrade document mentioned above. Upgrade-SPContentDatabase is not needed, the upgrade will be performed when you attach the database. Yes you'll have the same structure as before just relative to the new WebApplication.